# What should i do to put data from the controller in a directive?

Tags: angularjs

I've a scenario:

1) user clicks on a link and a request is sent (from a controller) to the backend to create a DB record.

2) the response is returned as a promise in the controller and am able to see the data from DB.

3) The link clicked in #1 opens a directive (element directive btw) which displays a popup window.

4) The controller and the directive are not related, but i need to show the data in the popup (opened by the directive).

I'm new to AJS and my knowledge is smattering. Should i use service/rootscope? to send data the promise to the directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your main question is how to get data into a directive.  I can think of two ways (there are probably more).

You can use the directive's isolate `scope` to pass in information from your controller.  You have few options for binding to this scope (see the [scope section of $compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)).   `=` for two-way binding or `&` for an expression binding `&`.  This might look something like

```
app.directive('myDirective', [
    function() {
         restrict: 'E',
         templateUrl: 'some template url',
         scope: {
             databaseRow: '='
         }
    }
])
```

Which would be used like this in the HTML

```
<my-directive database-row="controllerResult"></my-directive>
```

You can also create and inject a service into your directive, and move the DB logic into the directive.  You could have the controller `broadcast` an event or change a variable to trigger the directive, or even just have some visible element within the directive respond to a mouse click.